# Check whether file to be downloaded is empty or not before download, in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file to download using jquery which I achieve by `window.location.href`. But my challenge is that I need to find out whether the file which I intend to download is empty or not. If its empty, I need to show a popup showing error message, instead of downloading that empty file. But I don't know how to catch the file is empty or not before download using jquery.

I searched in net and I couldn't find an answer. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You'd have to make a separate request to the server to check the file size before initiating the download. The client has no way of knowing the file size in advance, without asking the server. But really why have you got empty files in the first place? Surely they should have not been allowed to be created? How did that situation occur? Or are you really talking about someone requesting a file which doesn't exist at all? It's not 100% clear.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can send a HEAD request to the URL to get the headers of the response. Then you can check the `Content-Length` value, something like this:

```
$.ajax('/yourfile.foo', {
  type: 'HEAD',
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    var size = parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'), 10) || 0;
    if (size != 0) {
      window.location.assign('/yourfile.foo');
    } else {
      console.log('invalid file, show an error here...');
    }
  }
});
```

This being said, prevention is a much better solution to this problem. You should amend your logic so that invalid files are not even displayed to the user. Allowing users to have the option to even select things they cannot have will just infuriate them.